# Use sequence generated by postgres (GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY) in jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a table :

```
CREATE TABLE COMMON.ACTION
(
    ID          INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    LABEL       VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
);
ALTER TABLE COMMON.ACTION ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

which generates a sequence :

```
schemaname | sequencename  | datatype | ...
common     | action_id_seq | integer  | ...
```

I'm trying to use this sequence in my entity as :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

//    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_GEN")
//    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false)
//    private int id;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false)
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false)
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "ACTION", schema = "COMMON")
public class ActionEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "action_id_seq ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "action_id_seq ", sequenceName = "action_id_seq ", allocationSize = 1, schema="COMMON")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String label;
}
```

Even if the name of the sequence matches the one existing in the DB, I keep getting error:

`[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [action_id_seq]`

When I use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, everything works fine but I want to use sequence because of batch inserts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the schema in `@SequenceGenerator`:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "action_id_seq ", schema="COMMON", sequenceName = "action_id_seq ", allocationSize = 1)
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it I still get the same error